# iOS animation （open the curtain）

Tags: ios, animation

[image]

Does anyone knows what's the app is? The animation is cool, how would you implement in code? 
It doesn't looks like its using the 2D graphic library, more like using a 3D graphic library (like OpenGL).

Comment: Someone has actually done this now :) marcus-experiments.tumblr.com/post/79887035850/curtain-mesh (Using Meek for iOS)

Answer (score 3):

[Googling by image](https://www.google.co.uk/search?tbs=sbi%3aAMhZZiu3ht3e3mwVnVkIH4lFQLjtCqImyaDI3eTmF15qKR0_1Hh6JQBAfc83Ht741fKmk6pza-wMmM84xlim5fsldo6OsdYecs3afzCsQ2rkQr7MnVfRxqbwP5cfcE6ZZr2NOFdwR8BS8hfzgYExNSZcL-4DRMsJB2KlBoTLviVBfewKa-uHYruWjEDV8SqtzDAYKQaGYlrvD3ZwIkIxRuBYQbHhbA45l7PtwXAxO_1RqrirfldARCYqAfgde1Bl5Sh1jTtzKisAUQhH84esJ-hub7UtBU7FYv3QVpmRY03l_1ZqmsQhKLvjT7f-Ob4IfahLaJ0egLNa3Xdt9UmuSNDdaAa24o8khZ5psg-2HqA0uNEaf3LLjFnoGNA4KJlz8-P94lsXNP2uND_1Dv9wdXpLCt0-4zUm--sNMDQ5dpNeVoFC4v0AN51J5qw4-7CoxhuSMGYuDs_1Z-5rDkR_18y_120eoURgj1749Br5nRs1xFHTxMnoqSru12Q2s5OrtOCewy77PXyhyA19OuFjf7h1aJPLrNaRUDjwTMR85rx8ySqqVd0t85p1ifpExVzACr7jK9YP0wXU3tF4dN_1FtX7a9PNuqQdaILlmtM96DJTv8Fv8fCUrDADcQNTWk45F2RPRHxivxeO2ptJdrDDIryCXSv_1BjkWIhabuabGwfWIGSlPWKKSi6JrsrcbrMx7zz8RoB26NLrNYYytwExaX1L-xaBtjB6250uUlJqKij1xBSvlk631-7RYISMQbPTsooZ0ED_1d4rPjPoRTlV8oVE8OzaW1iJdtpYq3VVImg7pV34RjH0kgxdEYODHVibluvr4fknXCab76TbiP5LtUwt7FkjvfnAQQk7mO8GblVTe8Y92KI6RD7F4sWE9rsVFCJ-e0OyLP_1BB7ivQraNvSJNpBDAMuVu02YyufIntZqzgDZtgWdBDyqYANAAF5yyIlwib0fqRkxLpZl5ueUUOTVNkbdOg-Hwgnn0GnZjmCSyevHMwcHxz4dG2eT1QXBupNlnD9ksSlpMSFVgj3BWycAJIwhV9AWhxT4S0qRDat6bCrTEupTLYR4X-knsIecUL3jeOaivUVrHuXdJAAO5_138zai6_1LCCuEx6sXaSRKO6bEXLijdAKnSRxB_1ZHTC1bqiPq_1JC16vuNPOBZoURyYKXmc3qr3rWGkkXLBeRPlQ-72h2zvh8aoMpP3CFkh9Mw8KqQHtnqeSu1w10pR3wq11yFovgDV8O74b2YUqHQNtvQfZlKVmYAf4hZCzZnAl8EWzO1EFtHiqpFDiX31MIXnDgTUgoVo0ED2i6MPlc6EwUA&bih=912&biw=1381) suggests that this is not a real app.  Its just a concept someone made on Photoshop.

> Slide Concept by Álvaro Carreras exhibits awe-inspiring, rather innovation sliding animation with curtain like effect.

Source: http://designmodo.com/vertical-side-menu-mobile-apps/#ixzz2ZllaTEOU

Making this would take a very large amount of effort, but I imagine open GL would be a good start.

Comment: I am confused is these are also a concept ?

https://vine.co/v/Mh5qd0HEpnt
http://marcus-experiments.tumblr.com/

Comment: @Vipul - wow - thanks for the link! So it turns out the guy who wrote wide sky https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/wide-sky/id592925278?mt=8 is working on a framework to actually achieve these kind of effects.  Hopefully it will be open source :)